# Install ubuntu on ssd disk fail

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, hardware-failure

I have just bought a SSD to update my old laptop. However I cannot install lubuntu on it, it stops and keeps repeating the same messages

```
ata3: hard resetting link
ata3: SATA link up 1,5 Gbps (SStatus 113 Scontrol 310)
ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
ata3.00: supports DRM functions and may not be fully accessible
ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33
ata3: EH complete
ata3.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
ata3.00: failed command: WRITE DMA EXT
ata3.00: cmd 3/00 <long numbers> tag 0 dma 52488 out
         res 40/<long numbers> Emask 0x4 timeout
ata3.00: status: { DRDY }

ata3: hard resetting link
ata3: SATA link up 1,5 Gbps (SStatus 113 Scontrol 310)
and so on....
```

I have plugged the disk into my desktop and it installs on there but I can't install lubuntu on my laptop. The laptop model is packard bell mz35 and the SSD is a samsung EVO 850 120GB.

Also the laptop works fine with the old HD but not with the SSD

What would cause this?

Comment: If you get no answer here in a few days, then request that question is moved to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you sure the drive is secured/installed properly?  Verify that it's making proper contact with the connectors in your laptop (some SSDs can be a bit touchy).  Lubuntu aside, can you install any other OSes on the drive, or access it at all by booting Lubuntu from the install media?  You might also find [this question on Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133946/are-these-sata-errors-dangerous) useful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect your laptop's SATA controller isn't modern enough in some aspect or another to run the SSD. I have had issues with older SATA controllers, like the Marvell SATA III controller in my x58 board, not being stable with SSDs; I suspect this is more of the same. As I understand it, the fundamental problem is with how fast the SSD responds back to requests from the controller, such that the controller doesn't see the drive's response. Or something along those lines.

As a last resort, check the SATA controller's UDMA settings in BIOS if you can. AFAIK it should be higher than UDMA/33 if you can set it higher.